# "403 Forbidden" when use python urlib package to download the image

Tags: python, web-crawler

i am new to urllib package.
i try to download all the images in website "http://www.girl-atlas.com/album/576545de58e039318beb37f6"
the question is: when i copy the the url of an image, and pass the url to a browser, i will get an error **"403 Forbidden"**. However, when i right click an image in the browser, and choose to open the image in a new window, this time, i will get the image in the new window.
the problem is: how the urlib simulates the second way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is forbidden to use the URLs outside a broweser. To ensure this, browsers send always a referer, the site, from which the image is loaded. If a browser would be written in Python, this would look like this:

```
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.addheader('Referer', 'http://www.girl-atlas.com/album/576545de58e039318beb37f6')
image = opener.open('http://girlatlas.b0.upaiyun.com/41/20121222/234720feaa1fc912ba4e.jpg!lrg')
data = image.read()
image.close()
```